# delete values from dataset

Tags: asp.net, dataset

i have an dataset with 3 tables in it they have a masterchild relationship,
lets  say the dataset is  like this

department table

```
deptID  departmentname
 1      IT
 2      CS
 3      EC
```

employee  table

```
empID  Empname DeptID
1      kiran    1
2      manu     2
3      kumar    3
4      ajay     3
```

now i have to delete value deptID =3 from  department table

then all the  employee who have DeptID ='3'  have  to  be  deleted from Employee table

how  do we do in dataset , is there any  builtin  function

thanks

Prince5

Comment: maybe the lowest mehode? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a ForeignKeyConstraint and set the rule to cascade:

```
 ForeignKeyConstraint fk = new ForeignKeyConstraint(dtDepartment.Columns["deptID"], dtEmployee.Columns["DeptID"]);
 fk.DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade;
```

Now when you delete records in the parent it will delete them in the children as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constraint to you dataset and enable cascade deleting
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35.aspx